# Is wildcard in Robots.txt in middle of string recognized?

Tags: robots.txt

I need some string for robots.txt like:

```
disallow: 

/article/*/
```

but I don't know if this is a proper way to do this or not?!

I need that for example:

```
    /article/hello
    /article/123
```

- may be followed; BUT:

  /article/hello/edit

  /article/123/768&goshopping
- the last lines would not be followed....

Comment: [Cross-post](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/68685/17633).

Answer (score 1):

Wildcards are not part of the original robots.txt specification, but they *are* supported by all of the major search engines. If you just want to keep Google/Bing/Yahoo from crawling these pages, then the following should do it:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /article/*/
```

Older crawlers that do not support wildcards will simply ignore this line.